# how to connect gdb to board (arm64, baremetal)

Tags: gdb, arm64

using the files I used before, to connect to arm64 board, I tried this.

```
etri@abss4:~/rrr/u-boot$ cat gdb_script 
target remote localhost:3333
set remotetimeout 10
monitor system_init
monitor sleep 2000
monitor soft_reset_halt
load
b main
b board_init_r
```

and the command is like this.

```
ddd --debugger aarch64-none-elf-gdb ~/U-BOOT/u-boot/spl/u-boot-spl.elf
```

I'm not sure if the debugger counter part in the FPGA is working yet.
By the way, the program (u-boot-spl.bin) is loaded to 0x400_0000 by another program and the linker made the .text start at 0x400_0000. I can see the source files in the ddd window.
I see in the telnet window,

```
accepting 'gdb' connection from 3333
dropped 'gdb' connection
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: What kind of JTAG debug probe are you using ? what are the messages being displayed by your debug probe software acting as the GDB server you are connecting to ?

Comment: Hi, the hardware colleague said the arm processor's debug circuit isn't yet connected to the jtag circuit. so I'm waiting until it's ready (before then, I'll just use printf).